# Xunit inject a collectionfixture that depends on another collectionfixture not working

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing, xunit

The situation is that I have a test class that needs a `CollectionFixture` injected, this latter needs another one to be injected to it also. This is not working.

This is my collection definition

```
[CollectionDefinition(nameof(AssemblyFixtures ))]
public class AssemblyFixtures :
    ICollectionFixture<DataMock>,
    ICollectionFixture<ItemCatalogSearchApiFactory>
{
}
```

And I have a test class :

```
[Collection(nameof(AssemblyFixtures))]
    public class TestBase
    {
        private readonly ItemCatalogSearchApiFactory _apiFactory;
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper _outputHelper;

        public TestBase(ItemCatalogSearchApiFactory apiFactory, ITestOutputHelper outputHelper)
        {
            _apiFactory = apiFactory;
            _outputHelper = outputHelper;
        }
    }
```

and `ItemCatalogSearchApiFactory` that needs `DataMock`

```
[Collection(nameof(AssemblyFixtures))]
public class ItemCatalogSearchApiFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    public ItemCatalogSearchApiFactory(DataMock dataMock)
    {            
        //using DataMock for some reason here
    }
}
```

This doesn't work and it fails to instantiate `ItemCatalogSearchApiFactory` with the following error thrown :

> Message: 
> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Collection fixture type 'XXXXXXX.IntegrationTests.ItemCatalogSearchApiFactory' had one or more unresolved constructor arguments: DataMock dataMock) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: ItemCatalogSearchApiFactory apiFactory)
> ---- Collection fixture type 'XXXXXXX.IntegrationTests.ItemCatalogSearchApiFactory' had one or more unresolved constructor arguments: DataMock dataMock
> ---- The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: ItemCatalogSearchApiFactory apiFactory
> Stack Trace: 
> ----- Inner Stack Trace #1 (Xunit.Sdk.TestClassException) -----
> ----- Inner Stack Trace #2 (Xunit.Sdk.TestClassException) -----

Is this the normal behavior ? Any Idea how should correct this situation ?

Answer (score 1):

*xunit* doesn't support dependent fixtures, it won't resolve order of fixture instantiation.

Apart from that, I see here misuse of *ICollectionFixure* interface. *xunit* has 3 ways of managing shared state in tests:

- *IDisposable* interface - *xunit instantiates a new test class instance* for each *Fact* attributed method in the test class, so code that will be put inside *Constructor* and *Dispose* method will be executed before each and after each test method correspondingly. It has *IAsyncLifetime* counterpart for  *async* code if needed.
- *IClassFixure* interface - used to inject fixture that are defined with *IDisposable*\*IAsyncLifetime* in a test class code. *xunit* will inject an instance of *SomeClass* in a test class marked with *IClassFixture<SomeClass>* which will be *SHARED ACROSS ALL TESTS* in that test class.
- *ICollectionFixture* together with *CollectionDefinition* and *Collection* is used to define shared state across *MULTIPLE TEST CLASSES*.

[xunit docs on shared state](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context)

If you really need to have dependent fixtures, you'll have to compose them together in a separate fixture and that new fixture use with *ICollectionFixture* or *IClassFixture* depending on your case.